# Discrete 3D Plot with date on one axis

Tags: plotting, manipulate

1) How do I plot the following data in 3D (large data, only a part of it is used here):

```
{ 
{"date", "v1", "v2"}, 
{{2000, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 10.4324, 11.084}, 
{{2000, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.75499, 11.02}, 
{{2000, 7, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 10.0905, 10.932}, 
{{2000, 7, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 10.2406, 11.249}, 
{{2000, 8, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 10.1241, 11.411}, 
{{2000, 8, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.92124, 11.4}, 
{{2000, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, 8.63775, 11.566}, 
{{2000, 9, 22, 0, 0, 0.}, 8.52399, 11.507}, 
{{2000, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.09311, 11.635}, 
{{2000, 10, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 8.68255, 11.626}, 
{{2000, 11, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 8.19321, 11.696}, 
{{2000, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.47059, 11.296}, 
{{2000, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.75926, 11.469}, 
{{2000, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 10.0035, 11.343}, 
{{2000, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.5563, 10.946}, 
{{2001, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.66618, 10.67}, 
{{2001, 1, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.57756, 10.57}, 
{{2001, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, 9.47097, 10.33}, 
{{2001, 2, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 8.86714, 10.11} 
}
```

2) I want to see how data evolves as time changes. How do I use `Manipulate` to do this?

Comment: Could you tell us which data should be on x-, y-, and z-axis? 
Regarding the second question: Why don't you convert your dates to simple numbers (e.g. hours) and plot then these dates and v1 or v2 with `ListPlot`? then you see how v1 and v2 changes with time.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert first your data, so that you can handle them in an easier way.
First I skip the information about the columns (the header) with

```
data2 = data[[2 ;; -1]];
```

then I convert the times (year, month, date, etc.) with something like

```
data3 = Transpose[{data2[[All, 1, 1]] + data2[[All, 1, 2]]/12 + 
data2[[All, 1, 3]]/(12*31), data2[[All, 2]], data2[[All, 3]]}];
```

and add the other columns into data3 again.

The rest is easy:

Use `ListPlot3D[data3, AxesLabel -> {"time", "v1", "v2"}]` for your 3D-plot. And `ListPlot[data3[[All, {1,2}]], AxesLabel -> {"time", "v1"}]` to plot v1 as function of the time (change `{1,2}` to `{1,3}` for v2).
If you really want to use `Manipulate`, try something like `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data3[[1 ;; a, {1, 3}]]], {a, 1, Length[data3], 1}]`.

You could also work without converting your dates. Then you could use `DateListPlot[data2[[All, {1, 2}]]]` or similar. But I fear that you need to convert your dates for the `ListPlot3D`.

Anyway, I hope you can adapt this answer to your needs. If not, ask again (and give more details about your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Graphics3D` to display the `{t, x, y}` trajectory together with projections on the  `y == ymin`, `x == xmax` and `t = tmin` planes:

```
data2 = {AbsoluteTime @ #, ##2} & @@@ Rest[data];

Dynamic[t = Clock[{1, Length @ data2, 1}, 5, 10]; 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[.01], Line[data2[[;; t]]], Green, Thin, 
   Line[{#, #2, Min[data2[[All, 3]]]} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]],  Orange, 
   Line[{#, Max[data2[[All, 2]]], #3} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]], Purple, 
   Line[{Min[data2[[All, 1]]], ##2} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]], LightBlue, 
   EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.2]], 
   Cuboid[Min /@ Transpose[data2], 
      Prepend[Max /@ Transpose[data2[[All, 2 ;;]]], data2[[t, 1]]]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> {Graphics`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, 
      5, {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}] &, Automatic, Automatic},  
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"t", "x", "y"}), 
  PlotRange -> (Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[data2])]]
```

[image]

Or, use `Animate` or `Manipulate` instead of `Clock`:

```
Animate[Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[.01], Line[data2[[;; t]]], Green, 
   Thin, Line[{#, #2, Min[data2[[All, 3]]]} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]],  
   Orange, Line[{#, Max[data2[[All, 2]]], #3} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]], 
   Purple, Line[{Min[data2[[All, 1]]], ##2} & @@@ data2[[;; t]]], 
   LightBlue, EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.2]], 
   Cuboid[Min /@ Transpose[data2], 
     Prepend[Max /@ Transpose[data2[[All, 2 ;;]]], data2[[t, 1]]]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, 
  Ticks -> {Graphics`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, 
      5, {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}] &, Automatic, Automatic},  
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"t", "x", "y"}), 
  PlotRange -> (Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ Transpose[data2])], 
 {t, 1, Length@data2, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on having 3D data, then, as @partial81 has pointed out, just give your data a little massage and then use `ListPlot3D`.

```
dates2000 = 
    data /. {{yr_, mo_, d_, h_, mi_, s_}, x_, y_} :> {
     DateDifference[
        DateList[{2000, 1, 1}], 
        AbsoluteTime[{yr, mo, d, h, mi, s}]],
    x, y}

ListPlot3D[dates2000]
```

[image: listplot]

However, I think this is quite hard to read, especially when not interactive, and you can't really see what the data is trying to tell you. So to me this looks better:

```
dates = Transpose[
  data /. {{yr_, mo_, d_, h_, mi_, s_}, x_, y_} :> 
   {
     {DateString[{yr, mo, d, h, mi, s}], x},
     {DateString[{yr, mo, d, h, mi, s}], y}
   }]
DateListPlot[dates, 
   Joined -> True, 
   Filling -> {1}]
```

[image: datelistplot]