# Date ticks with SmoothHistogram3D

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, histograms

I would like to plot some data with `SmoothHistogram3D`, but one of the axis is *date*, and I would like the ticks to reflect that:

```
SeedRandom[2021];
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{3250368000, 3250454400}, 10000], 
                  RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10000]}];
SmoothHistogram3D[data]
```

[image: 3D smooth histogram plot]

The $x$ axis (with `10^9`) should be date. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163001/18767) might be useful, especially `` Graphics`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks` ``  but I did not manage to adapt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SmoothHistogram3D[data,
 Ticks -> {
   {#, DateString[#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "YearShort", " ", "Hour24Short", ":", "MinuteShort"}]} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[MinMax@data[[All, 1]], 5],
   Automatic,
   Automatic}
]
```

[image: with dates and times as ticks]

Look at the [documentation of `DateString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) to see how to customize the date string specification to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In versions 11.+, we can use `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` to get date ticks:

```
SeedRandom[2021];
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{3250368000, 3250454400}, 10000], 
   RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10000]}];

SmoothHistogram3D[data, ImageSize -> Large,
   Ticks -> {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 7,  
     {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}] &, 
      Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]